# What is the difference between BitVec and BitVecVal in z3

Tags: math, binary, z3, z3py

I'm having a hard time understand the difference between `BitVec` and `BitVecVal` . For example: Let's consider 32 bits we define as

```
>> from z3 import *
>> >>> x = BitVec(1337,32)
>>> x.sexpr()
'k!1337'
>>> y = BitVecVal(1337, 32)
>>> y.sexpr()
'#x00000539'
>>> (x+y).sexpr()
'(bvadd k!1337 #x00000539)'
```

I debugged it using `sexpr()` and it definitely seems both are different as `BitVec` printed `k!1337` and `BitVecVal` printed `#x000000539` (Which is hex of decimal 1337).

But I am having trouble figuring out what does that actually means `k!` etc. and what is the difference between both `BitVal` and `BitValVec` . Would be great if someone provide example too just like I provided to make it clear. Also guide when to use what ?

Answer (score 4):

BitVec produces a symbolic variable. The first argument to BitVec is a *name*. 
The name could be a string or integer, When you pass an integer, Z3 creates an internal symbol that gets printed as k!, where  is the integer you passed.

BitVecVal produces an expression representing a bit-vector constant. The value of the constant is the value of the first argument (modulo 2 to the power of the exponent passed in as the second argument)

Comment: and could you explain with example like where to use `BitVec` and when to use `BitVecVal` please.

Comment: Use `BitVec` to create variables. Use `BitVecVal` to create constants.